# checkin situation in login

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

Could you please help me to get a solution for my issue. I am using a SQL Server database and c# I have a gym and I want to check in my login client with his offer.

- By month.
- By count of days.

**Offer Table:**

```
| ID | startdate |  month |  day  |  enddate  |      type        |
| 1  | 2019-03-05|   3    | null  |2019-06-05 |Business Calendar |
| 2  | 2019-03-05|  null  |   30  |2019-04-04 |Day Calendar      |
```

**I try this code:**

```
try
{
    string che = @"(select count(*)from table where id='" + ID.Text + "' and startdate <='" + DateTime.Now + "' and endDate >='" + DateTime.Now + "' )";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand(che, con);
    int count = (int)sda.ExecuteScalar();
    if (count > 0)
    {
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [checkin] (ID,time,username) VALUES (@ID,@time,@username)", con))
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID.Text);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", txttime.Text);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Check In Sucssesfuly ................... ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "this ID Expired .....................", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Close();
}
```

**What I'm looking for is to add something to this code if it day calendar count days not check the end date to expired the ID**

**I have her first condition after three months
The second
Login 30 times or a day**

Comment: So what error are you seeing? It looks like the table name in the first SQL statement might be wrong, but we can't be sure on the information given.

Comment: @iakobski i don't have error in this code i just want to add something to this code if it day calendar count days not check the end date to expired the ID

Comment: Instead of the last where clause in your select statement, try `and ((month is not null and getdate() < dateadd(month, startdate) or (day is not null and getdate() < dateadd(day, startdate))`

Comment: @iakobski Please explain further if you can

Comment: Your question is not completely clear, but it sounds like you want your sql statement to return 1 if today's date is the startdate or later, and today's date is less than 30 days/less than three months after the startdate. If this is not the case, describe what you actually do want.

Comment: @iakobski I have two cases first three months later and the second login 30 times or a day.

Comment: Do **NOT** use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)